# Как написать код, чтобы вычитало одну ячейку жизни?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Работаю над Баскетбол Шутером на юнити. Делаю ту часть, которая отвечает за вычитание ячеек жизни. Та часть кода, которая отвечает за добавление баллов срабатывает при касании с компонентом "Bonus" и добавляет баллы, но последующая часть кода, которая отвечает за уменьшение здоровья не срабатывает. По задумке это должно происходить после того, как мяч не попадет по объекту "Bonus" и соприкоснется с объектом "Terraine". Вопрос: Как написать код, чтобы при отсутсвии касания с Объектом "Bonus" и при последующем касании с объектом "Terraine" вычиталась ячейка жизни и объект 3hp выключался и включался объект 2hp и потом при последующем непопадания основным объектом на котором закреплен скрипт по объекту "Bonus" выключался объект 2hp и включался 1hp?

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public Rigidbody rb;
    [HideInInspector] public Collider col;
    [HideInInspector] public Vector3 pos { get { return transform.position;} }
    public static Score instance;
    
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text bestScoreText;

    public int health = 3;
    
    public GameObject hp3;
    public GameObject hp2;
    public GameObject hp1;

    

    int score = 0;
    int best = 0;

    void Awake ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
        col = GetComponent <Collider> ();

        //instance = this;
    }

    private void Start ()
    {
        best = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("best", 0);
        
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
        bestScoreText.text = "Best: " + best.ToString();
    }

    public void Push (Vector2 force)
    {
        rb.AddForce (force, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    public void ActivateRb ()
    {
        rb.isKinematic = false;
    }

    public void DesactivateRb ()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        //rb.angularVelocity = 0f;
        rb.isKinematic = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Terraine")
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-4f, 8f), Random.Range(2f, 7f), -0.2f);
            DesactivateRb(); 
        }
    }

    

    public void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        
        
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Bonus")
        {
            score += 2;
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
            if(best < score)
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("best", score);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.name != "Bonus") 
        {
            health = health - 1;
        }
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (health == 3)
        {
            hp3.SetActive (true);
            hp2.SetActive (false);
            hp1.SetActive (false);
        }
        if (health == 2)
        {
            hp3.SetActive (false);
            hp2.SetActive (true);
            hp1.SetActive (false);
        }
        if (health == 1)
        {
            hp3.SetActive (false);
            hp2.SetActive (false);
            hp1.SetActive (true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Забавно что вы решили делать отдельный if, вместо использования else

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов....

1. Навесить на бонус тэг. Да и на террейн тоже.
2. Хранить внутри мяча тэг обьекта последней коллизии. Думаю, что допустимо, даже, статическую переменную в даном случае.
3. На новой коллизизи вытягивать этот тег и смотреть. Если не бонус - вычетаем жизнь.